# WebBrowser Not Updating to Next Target URI (YouTube), Volume Control

Tags: c#, youtube, webbrowser-control, volume

I've been working on a C# Bot for Twitch for a while now, and I've been trying to get YouTube song requests going without having to use websites and such. I've been having a problem doing that in:

1. After the first song, it doesn't go to the next song
2. Can't control volume (which is needed) (Maybe through `WebBrowser` control or (`App` control)?

---

```
        public void RequestSongCmd(string user, string cmd) {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cmd) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(user)) {
                var song = GetSong(cmd);
                var conf = new Config();
                int response = AddSong(song);
                if (response == 1) {
                    MessageHandler(conf.Nick, user + ", song \"" + song.title + "\" (duration: " + song.duration + ") added to queue", 8);
                    user = song.requester;
                } else if (response == 0) {
                    MessageHandler(conf.Nick, user + ", song is too long.", 8);
                } else if (response == -1) {
                    MessageHandler(conf.Nick, user + ", invalid id.", 8);
                }
            }
        }
        public void StopSong(string usr) {
            var db = new Database();
            if (db.isMod(usr)) StopSong();
        }
        public class Song {
            public string id { get; private set; }
            public string title { get; private set; }
            public TimeSpan duration { get; private set; }
            public string requester { get; set; }
            public Song(string id, string title, TimeSpan duration) {
                this.id = id;
                this.title = title;
                this.duration = duration;
                this.requester = requester;
            }
        }
        public Song CurrentSong = null;
        public int TimeStarted, EstimatedEnding;
        private System.Threading.Timer NextSongTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(NextSong, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        public Song GetSong(string id) {
            using (WebClient w = new WebClient()) {
                w.Proxy = null;
                try {
                    JObject json = JObject.Parse(w.DownloadString("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + id + "&key=AIzaSyAXkTQTVZmZo0Thi2bbIer9PZIvzMgdTsk&fields=items(id,snippet(title),status(uploadStatus,privacyStatus),contentDetails(duration))&part=snippet,contentDetails,status"));
                    foreach (JToken song in json["items"]) {
                        if (song["id"].ToString() == id) {
                            if (song["status"]["uploadStatus"].ToString() == "processed" && (song["status"]["privacyStatus"].ToString() == "public" || song["status"]["privacyStatus"].ToString() == "unlisted")) {
                                return new Song(id, song["snippet"]["title"].ToString(), System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(song["contentDetails"]["duration"].ToString()));
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        public int AddSong(Song song) {
            if (song != null) {
                if (song.duration.TotalSeconds <= 900) {
                    List<string> songs = new List<string>();
                    if (File.Exists(@"data\Songs.txt")) {
                        songs = File.ReadAllLines(@"data\Songs.txt").ToList();
                    }
                    songs.Add(song.id + "|" + song.title + "|" + song.requester);
                    File.WriteAllLines(@"data\Songs.txt", songs.ToArray());
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        public void ReorderQueue(bool Remove = false, int start = 1) {
            if (File.Exists(@"data\Songs.txt")) {
                List<string> OldSongs = File.ReadAllLines(@"data\Songs.txt").ToList(), songs = new List<string>();
                for (int i = start; i < OldSongs.Count; i++) {
                    songs.Add(OldSongs[i]);
                }
                if (!Remove) {
                    for (int i = start - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        songs.Add(OldSongs[i]);
                    }
                }
                File.WriteAllLines(@"data\Songs.txt", songs.ToArray());
            }
        }
        public void SkipSong(string user) {
                try {
                    string name = user;
                    Database db = new Database();
                    var conf = new Config();
                    if (db.isMod(name.ToLower()) || conf.BaseAdmin.ToLower() == user.ToLower()) {
                        MessageHandler(conf.Nick, user + " has skipped the current song.", 8);
                        ReorderQueue(true);
                        PlaySong();
                    }
                } catch { 
                    #if DEBUG_ALL
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error has accord in skipping the song");
                    #endif
                }
        }
        public void PlaySong(Song song = null) {
            if (song == null) {
                foreach (string sSong in File.ReadAllLines(@"data\Songs.txt")) {
                    if (sSong != "" && (song = GetSong(sSong.Split('|')[0])) != null) {
                        song.requester = sSong.Substring(sSong.LastIndexOf('|') + 1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (song != null) {
                    CurrentSong = song;
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
                        this.SongRequest.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?video_id=" + song.id
                            + "&version=3&autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1&feature=player_embedded&controls=0&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&color=white&playerapiid=musicPlayer&iv_load_policy=3"));
                    }));
            }
        }
        public static void NextSong(object state) {
            var ts = new MainForm();
            ts.ReorderQueue();
            ts.PlaySong();
        }
        public void SongRequestPlayer_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e) {
            EstimatedEnding = (TimeStarted = GetUnixTimeNow()) + (int)CurrentSong.duration.TotalSeconds + 1;
            NextSongTimer.Change((int)CurrentSong.duration.TotalSeconds * 1000 + 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        public int GetUnixTimeNow() {
            return (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
        }
        public void StopSong() {
            TimeStarted = EstimatedEnding = 0;
            var form = new MainForm();
            NextSongTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
            form.SongRequest.Url = null;
            CurrentSong = null;
        }
    }
```

---

I've been under the assumption in order to control volume on the WebBrowser control it's best to just handle the entire application's volume, is that true?

And also, for the next song, what's happening there? It should work, it use to work. I have no idea what I've been doing wrong on that end for a while.

*I should note: I'm using `WinForms` for the entirety of the project, so `threading` isn't an issue because I've already tried a various amounts of methods in order to get this to work. As for the IRC Library I'm using `SmartIRC4Net`. *

***UPDATE:*** Fixed a few problems in the code, still can't figure out what to do next with next song,

Comment: If there is missing information please tell me, do not just vote down and walk away. It does not help.

Comment: I tried multiple things again, and nothing seems to have worked.